# Querying JIRA using SQL Server to return historical statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server, jira

**Update 20 March 2014**

Following Steve's advice below I came up with the following:

```
use JiraDB;
GO
With OrderedBugList AS
(
    SELECT  cg.issueid as "cgIssueID"
        ,cg.AUTHOR as "cgWho"
        ,cg.CREATED as "cgCreated"
        ,cg.ID as "cgID"
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cg.issueid ORDER BY cg.created DESC) as RowNumber
FROM changegroup cg
where cg.CREATED < '2014-01-10'
)

select  obl.RowNumber, 
    obl.cgCreated, 
    obl.cgID, 
    obl.cgIssueID, 
    obl.cgWho,
    ji.pkey,
    ji.summary,
    ci.NEWSTRING,
    ci.OLDSTRING 
from OrderedBugList obl
LEFT OUTER JOIN jiraissue ji on ji.ID = obl.cgIssueID
LEFT OUTER JOIN changeitem ci on ci.groupid = obl.cgID
where   obl.RowNumber = 1
and     ji.issuetype = 1
and     ci.FIELD = 'Status'
```

It didn't give me all I want, but it did solve the problem as I described.

**End Update**

I'm trying to create a historical view of a project, to demonstrate a trend in bug metrics.

I am using Atlassian JIRA (v4.4.4#664-r167664) with MS SQL Server 2008 R2

I have used the standard (from [Jira sample SQL Queries](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA#ExampleSQLqueriesforJIRA-FindStatusesofallissuesinaprojectonagivendate)):

```
SELECT JI.pkey, STEP.STEP_ID
FROM (SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
      FROM OS_CURRENTSTEP
      WHERE OS_CURRENTSTEP.START_DATE < '<your date>'
UNION SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
      FROM OS_HISTORYSTEP
      WHERE OS_HISTORYSTEP.START_DATE < '<your date>'
      AND OS_HISTORYSTEP.FINISH_DATE > '<your date>' ) As STEP,
(SELECT changeitem.OLDVALUE AS VAL, changegroup.ISSUEID AS ISSID
      FROM changegroup, changeitem
      WHERE changeitem.FIELD = 'Workflow'
      AND changeitem.GROUPID = changegroup.ID
UNION SELECT jiraissue.WORKFLOW_ID AS VAL, jiraissue.id as ISSID
      FROM jiraissue) As VALID,
jiraissue as JI
WHERE STEP.ENTRY_ID = VALID.VAL
AND VALID.ISSID = JI.id
AND JI.project = <proj_id>;
```

However I am finding that this is giving me the wrong result set.

I have taken to the changeitem table to try and dig for my gold. :)

```
SELECT cg.issueid 
  ,ji.pkey
  ,ji.SUMMARY 
  ,ci.FIELD
  ,CAST(ci.NEWSTRING AS varchar) AS NEWST
  ,CAST(ci.OLDSTRING AS varchar) AS OLDST
  ,cg.CREATED
  FROM changegroup cg
  LEFT OUTER JOIN changeitem ci on cg.ID = ci.groupid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN jiraissue ji on cg.issueid = ji.ID 
  where ci.FIELD = 'status'
  and ji.issuetype = 1
  and ji.PRIORITY = 1
  and cg.CREATED < '2012-09-15'
  order by ji.pkey, cg.created DESC, cg.issueid
```

My last stumbling block is to try and get only one record returned, i.e. the one record that has status in the timeframe required. The query above returns a result set that gives me something like:

- issueid / pkey / SUMMARY / FIELD / NEWST / OLDST / CREATED
- **32298 / QST-9693 / Bug Summary 1 / status / Closed / Resolved / 2012-09-12 17:11:46.560
- 32298 / QST-9693 / Bug Summary 1 / status / Resolved / In Progress / 2012-09-07 17:33:24.397
- 32298 / QST-9693 / Bug Summary 1 / status / In Progress / Open / 2012-09-07 17:32:40.623
- **32404 / QST-9789 / Bug Summary 2 / status / Resolved / In Progress / 2012-09-13 14:41:24.080
- 32404 / QST-9789 / Bug Summary 2 / status / In Progress / Open / 2012-09-10 17:43:07.663

I want to return only the records marked with double asterisks (**)

Pray tell how I may achieve this :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think you can create a SQL Fiddle to make it easier to play around with this: http://sqlfiddle.com/

You should be able to achieve what you want, i.e. first of each group, by using the:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)
```

clause. A full breakdown of how to use this is here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the prompt response. The first query is the one that is giving me the wrong data set. The second query is the one I am trying to fix. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks again, this only returns one record :(

Comment: Might be misunderstanding, but in your post you said you want to "only get one record returned". Can you please clarify this?

Comment: Yep, the query will return thousands of records, I have included the sample set to indicate I want to only get the top row of the three shown. So what I want to do is to retrieve one distinct row for the query for all of the record set. I'll edit the question some more to see if I can make it clearer.

Comment: Just read your updated post. To be absolutely clear, do you mean you want to return the first record for each issueid?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for, but it has to be the top record  for the criteria given, so it will be issueid and created that will be distinct.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I've updated my answer, this shows what method you need to use to solve it.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help, it solved the problem for me, however I now realise the problem was not as well defined as it should have been :) The query did return a good lot of the expected data set, but not all that was relevant :(